# Scala exception signature definition using generics

Tags: generics, scala

I'd like to use generics to define which business exception is thrown by a given method (the scala method will be called from Java so it must be in the signature).

Here's how I'd do it in Java:

```
public interface BaseInterface<T, E extends Throwable> {
    public T process(Class<E> wrapperExc) throws E;    
}

public class ExcOne extends Exception {}

public class SubclassOne implements BaseInterface<String, ExcOne> {
    @Override
    public String process(Class<ExcOne> wrapperExc) throws ExcOne {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's what I've attempted in Scala:

```
class UsingGenerics[IN, OUT, E <: Throwable] {

    //@throws(classOf[E]) - error: class type required but E found
    def process(request: IN, wrapperExc: Class[E]): OUT = {
        null.asInstanceOf[OUT]
    }    

}
```

and..

```
trait BaseTrait {

    type Request
    type Response
    type BusinessException <: Throwable

    //error: class type required but BaseTrait.this.BusinessException found 
    //@throws(classOf[BusinessException])
    def process(request: Request): Response    

}

class TraitImplementor extends BaseTrait {

    type Request = Input
    type Response = Output
    type BusinessException = BizExc

    def process(r: Request): Response = {
        if (1 != 2) throw new BusinessException("Bang")
        new Response
    }

}

class Input
class Output
class BizExc(msg: String) extends Exception(msg)
```

Both commented lines in the Scala code fail to compile.

I'd be grateful if someone could explain how to make this work.

To me, 'throw new BusinessException("Bang")' indicates that the type alias 'BusinessException' is a compilation time literal and as such I would have expected it to work with classOf.

If it turns out that it can't be done, I would also appreciate any insight as to what's happening with the type system or the order in which annotations are processed relative to the type substitution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, it would be the same in java for an annotation.
If you create annotation

```
public @interface Throwing { Class<? extends Throwable> exceptionType(); }
```

you could do `throwing{exceptionType = RuntimeException.class}` but not `throwing{exceptionType = E.class}`. You cannot do `E.class` in java nor `classOf[E]` in scala.

You cannot put a type parameter in an annotation. The problem is that in scala `@throws` is an annotation and follows the rules for annotations, but the rule for throws on the JVM are different. Maybe a special case would be warranted.

Comment: Thanks didierd, that makes perfect sense. 

I had hoped that the alternative use of abstract types in the trait example might work differently - perhaps even some lexical magic for the type literal substitution may have resulted in the compiler actually seeing @throws(classOf[NameOfActualBizExceptionType]) but it seems not.

I'll just accept that I need to do it differently and use a Java interface rather than a trait - that way I can use the formal type parameter in the throws position which, as you distinguished, is legal.